# UINib (iOS): possible to instantiate more than one view from a nib file?

Tags: ios, uiview, view, instantiation, uinib

I noticed that `UINib:instantiate(withOwner:options:)` returns an array. Does this mean that one nib file can contain more than one view? In every example I saw there was only one view, which was the first object in the array. What are the other (possible) elements in the array?

I'm asking because I'm trying to understand how this whole mechanism work, not so much because I want to work this way, so any theoretical background info will be welcome.

Thanks!

EDIT: if I can have more than one view in a nib file, how do I connect the second to a UIView subclass? There's only one `File's Owner`.

Comment: The [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8) has some useful info.

Comment: Already read it. Could not find an answer to my question, and the language is far from simple.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can have multiple views in nib file. For example.

A `Test.nib` with two root views. 
[image]

Load it

```
if let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Test", owner: nil) {
     print(views)
}
```

`views` will be an array of two. First element of array will be `UIView` and second will be `UITableViewCell`

[image]

Comment: So, what if I want to connect them to a subclass of UIView? Is that possible? There's only one file's owner

Comment: You can set the custom class in `Identity Inspector` for both views.